# Segmentation fault when generating many random numbers using PGI Fortran

Tags: random, cuda, fortran, fortran95, pgi

I need to generate a large amount of random numbers (from zero to 1, evenly distributed).

I initially had a Do loop and was generating random numbers on the fly as such:

```
Real :: RandomN
Integer :: N
DO N = 1, 10000
   Call RANDOM_NUMBER(RandomN)
   ... Some Code ...
ENDDO
```

However, I was getting a segmentation fault when generating the numbers (if I commented out the "call random_number(RandomN)" line, it worked fine).

Then after reading a post on the PGI forums(http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=713&highlight=randomseed). I decided to generate all the numbers first and put them in an array.

```
Real :: RndNum(1:10000,1:5)
Integer :: time(8), seed(2)
Call DATE_AND_TIME(values=time)     ! Get the current time 
seed(1) = time(4) * (360000*time(5) + 6000*time(6) + 100*time(7) + time(8))
Call RANDOM_SEED(PUT=seed)
Call RANDOM_NUMBER(RndNum)
```

However, this gives me a segfault straight away. I have tried a reduced version without the seed:

```
Real :: RndNum(1:10000,1:5)
Call RANDOM_NUMBER(RndNum)
```

This ***works for a few iterations of my code*** and then produces a segmentation fault as well. Am I using up some sort of memory? is there a way to clear it? or prevent it from being used up?

I have also tried:

```
CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count, count_rate, count_max)
CALL srand(count)

DO N=1, CAPN
   RndNum(N,1) = rand()
   RndNum(N,2) = rand()
   RndNum(N,3) = rand()
   RndNum(N,4) = rand()
   RndNum(N,5) = rand()
ENDDO
```

But this also gives a segfault.

Comment: If it gives you segfault, show the **full code**. Everything including `program` and `end program`. See [mcve]. Re your edit: what happened when you tried that?

Comment: The full code is a few 1000 lines long and involves multiple files. I have isolated the problem and tried to explain the bit that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your seed array is too small.  Get the minimum size like this:

```
program testpgi
  Real :: RndNum(1:10000,1:5)
  Integer :: time(8), seed(2)
  Integer :: min_seed_size
  Call DATE_AND_TIME(values=time)     ! Get the current time 
  seed(1) = time(4) * (360000*time(5) + 6000*time(6) + 100*time(7) + time(8))

  Call RANDOM_SEED(SIZE=min_seed_size)
  write(*,*) min_seed_size
end program testpgi
```

I just ran it on the PGI compiler, and got `34`.  If I do `Integer :: seed(33)`, it dumps core.  If I do `Integer :: seed(34)`, it does not.

Comment: Setting it to the seed to 34 or more, allows it to run for an iteration, after which it segfaults again. I tried setting it to 400 and it ran for 5 iterations, at 4000 only 1 iteration, then 6 iterations. So it seems to still be dumping core. Any ideas how to prevent it? (it is in a subroutine called and run on the host)

Comment: Then I think you have another problem.  I just ran with `seed(34)`, did BOTH `Call RANDOM_NUMBER(RndNum)` AND looped over a single random number 100,000 times.  No seg fault.  Did you check the min seed size for your version?

Comment: I checked the seed size and it is also 34. Should I `seed(1) = ...` or `seed = ...` so all elements of the seed array are assigned?, or should I seed them individually in a do loop?

Comment: That won't fix your problem. I only set seed(1), as you can see in my code, and it works fine.  At this point, I do not think the core dump is from RANDOM_NUMBER.  Have you put it in the debugger?